# How to make multiple conditions inside single filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make a filter based on checkboxes.

The thing is js ignoring other conditions inside filter when one is active

```js
filterData() {
  return this.airlines.filter(x => {
    if (this.filters.options.length != 0 || this.filters.airlines.length != 0) {
      for (let i = 0; this.filters.options.length > i; i++) {

        if (this.filters.options[i] == 0) {
          return x.itineraries[0][0].stops == 0;
        }

        if (this.filters.options[i] == 1) {

          return x.itineraries[0][0].segments[0].baggage_options[0].value > 0;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return x;
    }
  })
}
```

I know that return will stop the current loop, but is there any way to do it correctly?

Comment: `Array.filter` should return a **boolean**, that indicates if the current item should be in the result or not, build that boolean based on your conditions. Currently you are returning x (the item itself) on the `else` clause, that means that you are returning a `truethy` value => all the items will be included.

Comment: Try using `.includes` or `.some` for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @felixmosh, even if I change it to true result is the same, filter works when only one checkbox is checked, when i try to check  the second checkbox is still returning result of the first one and I am expecting it to return 1+2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update-1**:  (When to filter record for every case checked OR case)

Replace for loop and all conditions in a single return by && for if and || condition for data:

```
var chbox = this.filters.options;
return $.inArray(0, chbox) != -1 && x.itineraries[0][0].stops == 0 
    || $.inArray(1, chbox) != -1 && x.itineraries[0][0].segments[0].baggage_options[0].value > 0;
```

Hope this helps !!

`$.inArray(value, arr)` method will check for each checkboxes and will work for every checked ones .

**Update-2** (When to filter record for every case checked AND case)

As per comment below, you are trying to use checkbox on demand so use below code:

```
var chbox = this.filters.options;
boolean condition = true; 
if ($.inArray(0, chbox) != -1) {
   conditon = conditon && x.itineraries[0][0].stops == 0;
}

if ($.inArray(1, chbox) != -1) {
   conditon = conditon && x.itineraries[0][0].segments[0].baggage_options[0].value > 0;
}

return condition;
```

Comment: 2 checkbox can be active at the same time, so this  || 'or' won't do it. The problem is that it's not accepting x.itineraries[0][0].stops == 0 and  x.itineraries[0][0].segments[0].baggage_options[0].value > 0 at the same time. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: @Aksultan, Ok I got your point and updated my answer . Could you try now. This should work as per your need now !!

Comment: here is example https://codepen.io/Aksultan/pen/NWKeZGg?editors=1111, as you can see it's not working the way it meant to be

Comment: @Aksultan what you mean by not working ? Can you tell me the use case when it is failing ?
What I tried:  
Checked only first (Price more than 1000) returns  Book1, Book2, Book3
Checked only second  returns Book1, Book1

Checking both returns Book1, Book2, Book3, Book1 

If you change else case as `else{ return false;}`  then when nothing checked will return nothing. 

If any other case ? do let me know.

Comment: I am expecting it to return one result when both of them are checked : { "name": "Book1", "price": 1000 }. If I replace || with && it will make it, but the other cases will not work.

Comment: Okay, I have replied on your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060339/multiple-condition-filter/58060640#58060640

Also, updating this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function is returning an object, which ideally should be a boolean value. Please refactor the code as below.

```
filterData() {
  return this.airlines.filter(x => {
    let result = false;

    if (this.filters.options.length != 0 || this.filters.airlines.length != 0) {
      for (let i = 0; this.filters.options.length > i; i++) {
        if (this.filters.options[i] == 0) {
          result = x.itineraries[0][0].stops == 0;
          break;
        } else if (this.filters.options[i] == 1) {
          result = x.itineraries[0][0].segments[0].baggage_options[0].value > 0;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  })
}
```