# Multiple condition filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using multiple checkbox to filter it inside booksFilter function.

```
data() {
    return {
      books:[
        {
          name:"Book1",
          price:2000
        },
        {
          name:"Book2",
          price:2000
        },
        {
          name:"Book3",
          price:2000
        },
        {
          name:"Book1",
          price:1000
        }
      ],
      filters:{
        options:[]
      }
    }
  },
  computed:{

    booksFilter(){

      return this.books.filter(x => {

        if(this.filters.options.length>0){

          return this.filters.options.indexOf(0)!=-1 && x.price>1000
          || this.filters.options.indexOf(1)!=-1 && x.name == "Book1";

        }
        else{

          return true;

        }  
      })
    }
```

https://codepen.io/Aksultan/pen/NWKeZGg

It should return only one book, when both checkbox is used, but now it returns entire data.

Thanks

Comment: well, `this.filters.options.length` is not  `>0` and so you'll always return `true`, keeping every value. What exactly are you trying to filter out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
booksFilter() {
  return this.books.filter(x => {
    if (this.filters.options.length> 0) {
      boolean condition = true; 
      if (this.filters.options.indexOf(0)!=-1) {
         conditon = conditon && x.price>1000
      }

      if (this.filters.options.indexOf(1)!=-1) {
         conditon = conditon && x.name == "Book1";
      }

      return condition;
    else {
      return true;
    }  
  })
}
```

Hope it will resolve your case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as your filter is incorrect.

For simplicity purposes i divided into 2 sequential filters, one for each checkbox:

```
computed:{
    booksFilter(){
      return this.books.filter(x => {
        if(this.filters.options.length && this.filters.options.indexOf(0)!=-1){
          return x.price>1000;
        }
        else{
          return true;
        }  
      }).filter(x => {
        if(this.filters.options.length && this.filters.options.indexOf(1)!=-1){
          return x.name == "Book1";
        }
        else{
          return true;
        }  
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why to make code redundant ?  see my answer that has one-time computation.

Comment: every piece of code might be redundant and can be made more compact, this is why i noted in my answer that i splitted the code for simply understanding the problem with the condition

Comment: Yes, but if he has 10 checkboxes then he will use filters chaining to chain them one by one. Which is not a good approach, instead constructing a clause will be best. isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your logic like that to achieve the result:

```
return (this.filters.options.indexOf(0) === -1 || x.price > 1000)
  && (this.filters.options.indexOf(1) === -1 || x.name === "Book1");
```

`this.filters.options.indexOf(0) === -1 || x.price > 1000` - filter 0 is not selected, return true `OR` filter by `price`
`AND`
`this.filters.options.indexOf(1) === -1 || x.name === "Book1"` - filter 1 is not selected, return true `OR` filter by `name`